# how to save the output of two function which were run using two separate processors in python?

Tags: multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have two functions which are timeconsuming to be run. I wanna run each using multiprocessing library in python. I see some examples but I don't know once the processors have done with their calculations, how retrieve the output of each and sum up the total results? Each function returns a value.

```
For example:

from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def f1(n):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    global f1out
    f1out = n**2
    return n**2

def f2(n):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    global f2out
    f2out = n**2
    return n**3


start = time.time()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    results1 = Process(target=f1,args=(range(10)))
    results2 = Process(target=f2,args=(range(10)))
    results1.start()
    results2.start()

    results1.join()
    results2.join()


    print(results1)
    print(results2)



end = time.time()
TT = end-start
print(TT)
```

I wanna calculate the (results1 + results2)
but results1 and 2 are not values!